# Running python script that loads .sql file after package installation

Tags: python, scripting, package

So after my python package is installed, I want to run a python script that loads the data from the .sql file.  In my `setup.py` file I have

```
 setup(...,
 packages=['stuff', 'scripts'],
 package_data={'stuff': ['data/*.sql']},
 scripts=['scripts/load.py']
 )
```

However, after installation I am unable to run the load.py file as the .sql file cannot be found.  The load.py file is in my bin folder.  So I run python bin/load.py in my virtual env and I get no such file or directory: '.sql'.  How do I configure the .sql file so that I can successfully run load.py ?